# Jenkins DSL Plugin (>=1.77): Use gerrit-trigger in pipelineJob

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl, gerrit-trigger

I don't know how to use the gerrit-trigger plugin in a DSL pipelineJob. According to the [dsl plugin doc](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob-triggers) triggers is deprecated for pipelineJobs. And from the [wiki 1.77](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Migration#migrating-to-177) replaced by pipelineTriggers. So I have change my triggers section to

```
properties {
    pipelineTriggers {
        triggers {
            gerrit {
                events {
                    patchsetCreated()
                }
                project('**My/Git/Repo', '**')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I use pipelineTriggers i get the following

> ERROR: (configure_seed_jobs.groovy, line 25) No signature of method: events() is applicable for argument types: (configure_seed_jobs$_run_closure1$_closure4$_closure9$_closure10$_closure11$_closure12) values: [configure_seed_jobs$_run_closure1$_closure4$_closure9$_closure10$_closure11$_closure12@3bcd6c54]
>   Possible solutions: gerritProjects(), buildFailureMessage(), buildNotBuiltMessage(), buildStartMessage(), buildSuccessfulMessage(), buildUnstableMessage(), buildUnsuccessfulFilepath(), changeSubjectParameterMode(), commentTextParameterMode(), commitMessageParameterMode(), customUrl(), dependencyJobsNames(), dynamicTriggerConfiguration(), escapeQuotes(), gerritBuildFailedCodeReviewValue(), gerritBuildFailedVerifiedValue(), gerritBuildNotBuiltCodeReviewValue(), gerritBuildNotBuiltVerifiedValue(), gerritBuildStartedCodeReviewValue(), gerritBuildStartedVerifiedValue(), gerritBuildSuccessfulCodeReviewValue(), gerritBuildSuccessfulVerifiedValue(), gerritBuildUnstableCodeReviewValue(), gerritBuildUnstableVerifiedValue(), gerritSlaveId(), nameAndEmailParameterMode(), notificationLevel(), serverName(), silentMode(), silentStartMode(), skipVote(), triggerConfigURL(), triggerOnEvents()

What am I missing?

Comment: I now found the version specific API reference under https://<project-host-name>/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html. Listing API methods, some of which are in the "Possible solutions". 

Maybe the API hosted at https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/ should be pointing at the latest and greatest?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, because either events{..} or project() is no more available to gerrit in pipelineTriggers, you should use triggerOnEvents {..} and gettitProjects{...} instead. For more details, you could find them in the document on your jenkins (e.g. http://0.0.0.0:8080/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/)

```
properties {
  pipelineTriggers {
    triggers {
      gerritTrigger {
        gerritProjects {
          gerritProject {
            compareType('PLAIN')
            pattern('**My/Git/Repo')
            branches {
              branch {
                compareType('PLAIN')
                pattern('master')
              }
            }
          }
        }
      triggerOnEvents {
        changeMerged()
      }
    }
  }
}
```